# Adding Apache log export via Syslog still writing local log

Tags: apache-2.2, syslog, logging

we have configured syslog/syslog-ng to export Apache logs ton a dedicated log server, for security and log check reasons.

But I want to keep a copy of the error log on Apache server for easy understanding in case of problem. Here is the configuration file

```
ErrorLog        /space/www/vhost/data/logs/errors.log
ErrorLog        "|/usr/bin/logger -t vhost_error -p local6.info"

CustomLog       /space/www/vhost/data/logs/access.log combined
CustomLog       "|/usr/bin/logger -t vhost_access -p local6.info" combined
```

The access.log is on both servers (apache one and log one), but the errors.log is only on the log server. I don't figure out why.
Maybe I can configure syslog on the Apache server to write local log AND send it to the log server?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The ErrorLog directive can not be used multiple times.

You should configure syslog to keep a local copy.